# How fill all the area under the curve?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the next code

```
plt.plot(t,w_rot)
plt.fill_between(t, w_rot, 0, w_rot>0, color='b')
plt.fill_between(t, w_rot, 0, w_rot<0, color='r')
```

and the plot result varies of the value of the resolution, if I have a higher resolution of data the area it's filled completely:
[image]

If I have a lower resolution of data the filled area looks like this:
[image]

The `dt` variable it's the interval between time samples in seconds, `length` it's the total length of the pulse in seconds.

**How can the area be completely full in both scenarios?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ([see example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html))

```
interpolate=True
```